# Extension of scalars and bilinearity of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I just got introduced to the extension of scalars in the tensor product. Suppose I have $f:A\rightarrow B$ a homomorphism of rings and $M$ an $A$-module. We can view $B$ as an $A$-module, thus it makes sense to take $B\otimes_AM$. Now we give it a $B$-module structure by defining
$$
b(b\otimes x)=bb'\otimes x\,.
$$
So far I am okey with everything. I want to make sure I understand how this agrees with the bilinearity of the tensor product. So as the tensor product is seen as a tensor product of $A$-modules, it will be $A$-linear. If I take $a\in A$ then I can multiply $a$ with $x$ but not with $b$.

So would it be like this?

$$
a(b\otimes x)=(f(a)b)\otimes x = b\otimes (f(a)x)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in claiming that the tensor product is $A$-linear (or $A$-balanced). However, this does *not* entail the formula you wrote. One problem is that $f(a)x$ is not a sensible expression, since $f(a)\in B$ but $x\in M$, which is an $A$-module and not a $B$-module.

Recall that when defining the tensor product of two $A$-modules $N,M$ we take their tensor product $N\otimes M$ (the one constructed over $\mathbb Z$, viewing $N,M$ as abelian groups, equivalently, $\mathbb Z$-modules) and then add an additional relation:
$$
(a\cdot n)\otimes m\sim n\otimes(a\cdot m)
$$
(We also identify this common expression with $a\cdot(n\otimes m)$, but let us not worry about this too much)

I wrote $a\cdot n$ and $a\cdot m$, respectively, to emphasis this being the given $A$-module structure on $N$ and $M$, respectively. In our case, $B=A$ but with $A$-module structure induced by $f\colon A\to B$, i.e. $a\cdot b:=f(a)b$. Thus, your formula should be
$$
(f(a)b)\otimes m
=(a\cdot b)\otimes m
=b\otimes(a\cdot m)
=b\otimes(am)
$$
which are both evaluations of $a\cdot(b\otimes m)$.